# Customise Meteor Collection in server side

Tags: meteor

What is the proper way to create my own implementation of [Meteor.Collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) API in server side. My collection should have all features of the meteor.collection + my own methods. Also it must be reactive.

I can use my custom collection like this:

```
Posts = new Meteor.myCollection("posts");
  Meteor.publish("posts", function() {
  return Posts.find();
});
```

How can i achieve this.

Comment: You want to create a new collection implementation? Look at the source code for the core packages [`mongo-livedata`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/mongo-livedata) and [`minimongo`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/minimongo). This is a huge task that will take thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2 for an example.